# Is it possible to get windows event logs into application insights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, event-log, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

We have application insights running in our application (on premise and hosted in azure) and we are sending telemetry without issues, different resources, regular data, pageViews, exceptions, traces etc, recently I was asked to increase the telemetry data by adding Windows Event logs (from event viewer), but, to be honest, I am quite new with azure or application insights and all the documentation I find it a bit confusing, since all I find talks about azure monitor, log analytics workspaces configuration, but nothing clear enough (at least to me) that points me to get this data logged into application insights resources specifically. Is this possible to achieve? Something like adding a nuget package and configure applicationInsights.config?

> Update... I've followed your suggestions, and added the nuget package for EtwCollectorTelemetryModule, and modified the applicationInsights.config file.

This is how it looks now:
`<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.EtwCollector.EtwCollectorTelemetryModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.EtwCollector">                                               <Sources <Add ProviderName="Microsoft-Windows-Eventlog" Level="Warning" /> </Sources>`

But, I'm still not able to see any kind of logs in the traces table (if i understand correctly, logs will be sent to that table.) Do I need to initialize this module in order to start tracing these logs?
Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is this helpful:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-trace-logs#use-etw-events or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49403044/is-it-possible-to-log-windows-events-to-application-insights?

Comment: thanks, it is helpful, I will take a closer look at it!

Comment: I was just thinking, there is also [this repo](https://github.com/Azure/diagnostics-eventflow) that can help doing what you want.

Comment: Thanks @PeterBons I just updated my question with some details because I am still not able to see any logs in azure portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Peter Bons here. When you need to add Windows Event logs to azure application insights, you need to add ETW module in the config file.

And pls note here, the `EtwCollectorTelemetryModule` is an [asp.net module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/configuration-with-applicationinsights-config#etw-event-tracking) so that it suitable for asp.net application.

You can refer to [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net#add-application-insights-automatically) to modify the configuration if your program written in asp.net. Pls note, `Add Application Insights Telemetry` mentioned in the doc is the operation 'right click the project and click Configure Application Insights'

[image]