# Is there a way to setup an export of Log Analytics tables to Azure SQL database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-log-analytics

I am looking for way to automatically export data from a Log Analytics table into an Azure SQL database table?  Does anyone know how to do this on an automated schedule?

Comment: Can you share exactly how you have the logs? is it as tables in Blob storage ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To export log analytics data to Blob storage or ADLS, you can try one of below.

1. [Log Analytics – data export (preview)](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-monitor-blog/log-analytics-data-export-preview/ba-p/1783530) and  [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69764006/15969417)
2. [Archive data from Log Analytics workspace to Azure storage using Logic App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/logs-export-logic-app)

Next ....You can go for **Ingest** option in ADF.

[image]

Next, configure source linked service i.e. **Blob Storage** or [Azure Table storage linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-table-storage?tabs=data-factory#create-an-azure-table-storage-linked-service-using-ui) and Sink i.e. **SQL DB**

Or any relevant source or sink option you want as per the logs stored.

[image]